# How to add a value on the first position of a linked list in C with a function that can add in any position

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been trying to make a function where I can insert any value at any position, but I can't find the way to add to the first position of the list I have created.
For example, if  I have a list (1 2 3) and I want to add a 4 to the index 2 (or any  2 >= x <= size) it successfully gives me the list (1 4 2 3), but if I change the index to 1 my list does the same thing as (1 4 2 3). Whereas it should be (4 1 2 3)
My function is below.

```
 int add(LList* list, int index, void* value) {
 if ((LList_size(list) < index) || (index <= 0)) { return 0; }
 LList* temp = list;
 int tam = 0;
    //here is the error
  if (1 == (index)) {
         LList* new = LList_create();
         new ->value = value ;
         new ->sig = temp->sig;
         temp->sig = new ;
         return 1;
     } 

 while (temp != NULL) {

     if (tam  == (index - 2)) {
         LList* new = LList_create();
         new ->value = value ;
         new ->sig = temp->sig;
         temp->sig = new ;
         return 1;
     }
     tam++;
     temp = temp->sig;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

---------------------EDIT--------------------

I tried to reduce this, but still the same inconvenience.

```
int add(LList* list, int index, void* value) {

if ((LList_size(list) <= index) || (index < 0)) { return 0; }
LList* temp = list;
int tam = 0;
//si le paso 1 tiene que insertar uno antes de 1

while (temp != NULL) {
    if (tam  == index) {
        LList* new= LList_create();
        new->value = valor;
        new->sig = temp->sig;
        temp->sig = new;
        return 1;
    }
    tam++;
    temp = temp->sig;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Considering the `list` passed to the function is head of the list, you need to do some changes. 1) `new->sig = temp` (considering `sig` represent the next node) and remove `new->sig = temp->sig`, `temp->sig = new` lines as you want the new node at head, 2) pass address of `list` (pass a double pointer) as head itself will be changed and in the `if`  block set `*list = new`

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing in C always start from 0 , your whole code assumes it starts from 1.
For example an array of length 3 starts with index 0 and ends with index 2
so for example this line of code should be:

```
if ((LList_size(list) =< index) || (index < 0)) { return 0; }
```

go over the code again with this in mind and it should work for you.

Comment: You're right about the indexing, but even if that changes, the problem still persists sadly :(, as I am still not able to change the first node.